# QGIS Batch Processing error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, error, python-2.7, batch

I receive the following below error when trying to run Batch Processing in QGIS. I have tried uninstalling QGIS but still this problem persists.

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'

Traceback (most recent call last):

File"C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\BatchAlgorithmDialog.py",
   line 78, in accept
       alg = self.alg.getCopy()   
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerAlgorithm.py",
   line 201, in getCopy
       newone.algs = copy.deepcopy(self.algs)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in
   deepcopy
       y = copier(x, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 257, in
   _deepcopy_dict
       y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in
   deepcopy
       y = copier(x, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 298, in
   _deepcopy_inst
       state = deepcopy(state, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in
   deepcopy
       y = copier(x, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 257, in
   _deepcopy_dict
       y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in
   deepcopy
       y = copier(x, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 298, in
   _deepcopy_inst
       state = deepcopy(state, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in
   deepcopy
       y = copier(x, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 257, in
   _deepcopy_dict
       y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 190, in
   deepcopy
       y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 334, in
   _reconstruct
       state = deepcopy(state, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in
   deepcopy
       y = copier(x, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 257, in
   _deepcopy_dict
       y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in
   deepcopy
       y = copier(x, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 230, in
   _deepcopy_list
       y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in
   deepcopy
       y = copier(x, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 298, in
   _deepcopy_inst
       state = deepcopy(state, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in
   deepcopy
       y = copier(x, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 257, in
   _deepcopy_dict
       y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 190, in
   deepcopy
       y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 334, in
   _reconstruct
       state = deepcopy(state, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in
   deepcopy
       y = copier(x, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 257, in
   _deepcopy_dict
       y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in
   deepcopy
       y = copier(x, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 257, in
   _deepcopy_dict
       y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 190, in
   deepcopy
       y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 334, in
   _reconstruct
       state = deepcopy(state, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in
   deepcopy
       y = copier(x, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 257, in
   _deepcopy_dict
       y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 190, in
   deepcopy
       y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 334, in
   _reconstruct
       state = deepcopy(state, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in
   deepcopy
       y = copier(x, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 257, in
   _deepcopy_dict
       y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 190, in
   deepcopy
       y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 334, in
   _reconstruct
       state = deepcopy(state, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 163, in
   deepcopy
       y = copier(x, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 257, in
   _deepcopy_dict
       y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 190, in
   deepcopy
       y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 343, in
   _reconstruct
       y.__dict__.update(state) 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Python version: 2.7.5

QGIS version: 2.14.3

**This is the Model that I wish to run this Batch Process** , this model runs fine on the individual level.
[image: Model]